# Wrong request parameters when testing an api route

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, controller, phpunit

I have a test that calls a function in a controller:

```
public function testAuthentication()
{
    $user = $this->createUser();
    $this->actingAs($user)->withoutMiddleware();
    $project = $user->project();
    ...
    $response = $this->post("/api/projects/$project->id/store", [
        'param' => 'testparam'
    ]);
    ...
}
```

The route looks like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'projects'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{project}'], function () {
        Route::post('store', [MyController::class, 'store']);
    });
});
```

And the function `store` looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request, Project $project): void
{
    dd($project);
    ...
}
```

When i start the test and i debug the controller function, i can see that `$project` is empty, meaning it doesnt have any attribute. However when i change the function header to:

```
public function store(Request $request, string $project): void
{
    ...
    MyModel::create([
        ...
        'project_id' => $project->id
    ]);
])
```

and i debug, i get the right id.

When i call this function normally from the browser request it works, but when i call it from the test file it only works with `string`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you need to use `postJson` instead of `post` and I assume you're using resourceApi route !,  and you're using implicit routing which is when ID:1 for example not exists will fire 404

Comment: You have no route parameter defined for the project model. It should look like `/api/projects/{project}/store` not just `store`.

Comment: For this question to be answered correctly you need to show the complete routes, not just the nested route. Start from the beginning.

Comment: In this example in the Controller i use the $project to create a new record in the database and if i give a non-existing project id through the route, i get the error `Integrity constant violation: 1048 Column 'project_id' cannot be null ...`

The Route i use is inside a group, inside another group and id does have /project/{project}/store (i updated the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, what are you getting when you have `Project` instead of `string`, because "is empty" could mean that it is a `Project` with no data (no attributes, just the object) or it is `null`, and the later would make no sense... What database connection are you using?

If I am not confused, you are using `withoutMiddleware` and that is removing the Middleware that is doing the `implicit binding`, so you will always get an empty Project object, so remove `withoutMiddleware` and try it again...

You [can see](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/25070a3ffb175c15b59cd7f12289a9648165bba3/app/Http/Kernel.php#L38) you have a middleware doing the binding replacement, and that [middleware's code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4b4b1e489623c4c7c31447a2bc06450050f0686e/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php#L36-L51) is explicit about doing so. Well, `withoutMiddleware` is removing it, so you will just have the normal Dependency Injection behavior.

Personally, if you have to use `withouthMiddleware`, it should either be a Unit test (instead of a feature) or define everything you are expecting to have on that route you are asserting, else you are defining half the data your case needs, and that is not good (for a Feature test).

Comment: When i have Project instead of string i get an empty Project, also im using mysql.
When i remove withoutMiddleware i get the error "Unauthenticated"

Comment: You have to pass whatever is allowing you to authenticate, if you use `withoutMiddleware` you are literally removing the middleware responsible for understanding `{project}` = the ID you passed, so you must not use `withoutMiddleware`, what are you using to authenticate? You do have `$this->actingAs($user)`, if that is not working, you either need to specify the `guard` or that user, as it is, is not allowed (but that should be a `403` not a `401`)

Comment: i put `$this->actingAs($user, 'api')` and removed `withoutMiddleware` not it worked, Thanks